# How can I remove Recently Viewed Products individually using delete(icon) button?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.2.11

I want to add a delete button link to the recently viewed products and when we click on delete button link of any product then it should be remove from the list.

You can see image for better understandings:

[image]

Please help me to implement this functionality, I will be very thankful to you.